# UWP MySQL error : Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts

Tags: mysql, uwp

This simple code shows an error in a UWP application : *MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.'*

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
string connString = "Server=serverName; Uid=user; Password=password; Database=db; SslMode=none";
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString);
conn.Open();
Console.WriteLine($"Mysql version : {conn.ServerVersion}");
conn.Close();
```

The problem is that exact same code works perfectly fine when creating a Console app with .net framework 4.8, and also a console app built in .net Core 5 or 6.

Do you have any idea of what may causes this error message in UWP ?

Edit : no matter which sql connector is used, the result is always the same.
Edit 2 : server is another computer, located on the same lan.

Answer (score 0):

If you are connecting to the localhost, please make sure [Enabling loopback for a UWP application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/develop-your-app/loopback#enabling-loopback-for-a-uwp-application) in your device. UWP apps have limitations because it's running in the sandbox, so if you want to connect to the local host, it is necessary to enable the local loopback for your device.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but the server is another computer on the same lan.

Comment: @LockedInside Have you enabled  `privateNetworkClientServer`, `InternetClien&Server` and `Enterprise Authenticacion` capabilities in the manifest file?